# Cast custom propertiesfile to complex type object in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file

I build a custom properties file in java 1.8 ,I can read it lie properties but what I want to do that can I get this properties file with complextype object.I dont want to read with key and value I want to cast it directly to object ,How can I do that

```
//Connection properties is my custom properties file class
      prop = new Properties();
            String filename = "connection.properties";
            input = ConnectionProperties.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
            if(input==null){
                System.out.println("Sorry, unable to find " + filename);
                return;
            }

            //load a properties file from class path, inside static method
            prop.load(input);

            Enumeration<?> e = prop.propertyNames();
            while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                String key = (String) e.nextElement();
                String value = prop.getProperty(key);
                System.out.println("Key : " + key + ", Value : " + value);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@ConfigurationProperties` from SpringBoot.

Read more about it here: https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot